# How to import/load classes into a jenkinsfile from another file

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to import custom classes defined outside of my jenkinsfile. These classes have constructors which require parameters. I've already tried using load() for each of the class files, but it seems this only works for script files that just define static methods. When I tried using this to load my class files, it threw an error that it could not find an `<init>` method.

I currently have a way of importing these classes that works, but it requires re-cloning the repository as a library (code below). I'd like to move away from this since it's inefficient and seems like it should be unnecessary.

current working (but not great) implementation:

Jenkinsfile:

```
lib = library(identifier: "<libraryName>@${env.currentBranch}",
                      retriever: modernSCM([$class: 'GitSCMSource',
                      credentialsId: <credentialsId>,
                      id: '<id>',
                      remote: env.projectRemote,
                      traits: [[$class: 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait']]])).com.company.jenkins.sdk

def git = lib.Git.new(this, currentStage, currentStep)
...
```

src/com/company/jenkins/sdk/Git.groovy:

```
package com.company.jenkins.sdk.Git

class Git implements Serializable {
    def script
    def stage
    def step

    Git(script, stage, step){
        ...
    }
}
```

I'd like to get rid of that library command and replace it with a simpler way of importing these classes.

Comment: I'm guessing you've already looked at shared libraries right?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately they're not an option for our particular use case : /

Comment: Jenkins Pipeline shared library feature was designed to do exactly that.

Comment: Shared libraries are good if you have >1 project you want to use them in (hence the name "shared library"), but if all you want to do is load some Groovy classes in your job, it kind of sucks. The `load` method seems to only work for functions, and most work-arounds require security exemptions for untrusted code.